# Unable to debut SSIS Script Task with VS 2017 15.8.7 and SSDT for SQL 2016

Tags: debugging, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

I have an SSIS Project built in Visual Studio 2017 with Data Tools for SQL 2016, and I'm unable to debug any of the Script Tasks.  I create break points which shows the red dot in the designer, but none of them ever hit.  I'm not getting any errors or warning, or not sure where to check if I am getting any.  I'm having to put Message Boxes in to walk through the code.

I've tested with Run64BitRuntime as True and False with the same results.  I've also tried updating the "Optimize Code" option in the Build properties within the Script Task running checked and unchecked with the same results.

Any suggestions or thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Had the exact same issue just the other day.   I'm VS 2017 15.8.2.  Reinstalling SSDT using the standalone installer resolved the issue for me.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @TimMylott Thanks for the suggestion, but alas this didn't work.  Must be something else.  Appreciate the response.

Comment: Just checked Event Log, and I'm also getting this when trying to debug:


`The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{2DC39BD2-9CFF-405D-A2FE-D246C976278C}
 and APPID 
{DB336D8E-32E5-42B9-B14B-58AAA87CEB06}

to the user mydomain\myuserid SID (S-1-5-21-996407614-3994743200-3141852476-43026) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable).`